# Overleaf - includegraphics is not working: empty images

Tags: graphics, ieeetran, overleaf, includegraphics

I was getting a "no BoundingBox" error in my file and I saw that to solve my problem I should convert .png files to .eps. Done. Now, the errors disappeared but the figures are not visible. Here is the code:

```
\begin{figure}[ht!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{RedeUsina.eps}
\caption{Some caption here}
\label{fig:arq}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[ht!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth,]{AmbienteTestes.eps}
\caption{Some caption here.}
\label{fig:amb}
\end{figure}
```

The spaces of the images are generated, but just the empty spaces, nothing visible (no images).

I would like to know how to solve this. I am using a variant of the IEEE tran, named `sbrt2018port.cls`.

Comment: I guess overleaf would use pdflatex by default,  in which case eps files would not be allowed  and converted to png in the background  anyway.  What you have done confuses me.

Comment: (I'm a support personnel at Overleaf) .eps files _are_ allowed with pdflatex + Overleaf; `--shell-escape` is enabled by default and would convert it to .pdf. (Re security concerns: Each Overleaf project is in its own Docker container so the `-shell-escape` would only affect your own project.) However the original "No bounding box" messages may mean your original .png files are missing metadata re its dimension. If you email support@overleaf.com and let us know your project URL, we can have a closer look for you.

Comment: If you got a no bounding box error with png-files then you perhaps used latex instead of pdflatex.

Comment: @Johannes_B , I was using .png files, but I was receiving the "no BoundingBox" error. When I searched about, I saw people talking about the .eps files and tried.

Comment: In Overleaft, we can specify pdflatex, @Ulrike . I specified that, but the error continued. So I tried another approach (.eps).

Comment: If you are really using pdflatex then png should work unless they are broken. Try with e.g. example-image.png to test. If it fails with this image too you are perhaps changing the output mode in your code.

Comment: I tried with other .png files, @Ulrike . Same error.

Comment: I will contact the Overleaf support, as suggested by you, @LianTze .

Comment: Compile without images and check in the log-file (at the end) if a pdf is created.

Comment: I've now had a look at `sbrt2018port.cls`; it contains `\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}`. Removing the `dvips` solves the problem: `graphicx` is smart enough to know what driver to use anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sbrt2018port.cls` (a copy can be found [here](http://www.sbrt.org.br/sbrt2018/modelos/sbrt2018port.cls)) has a line `\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}`, so `.png` files cannot be processed correctly even if you use pdflatex to compile your project.

Removing the `dvips` on that line, so that `graphicx` can use the suitable driver to process image files, solves the problem. `graphicx` is smart enough to know which driver to use anyway, based on the engine used to compile your document.